# Match between column values returned from LIKE constraint in SQL

Tags: design-patterns, constraints, matching, sql-like

I am trying to match column values returned, but values are returned as a result of pattern matching:

```
select app.employees.id, app.employees.name, app.employees.current_bp, 
app.designation.designation from app.employees, app.designation 
where app.employees.id like 'khsn?' = app.designation.desig_id like 'khsn?';
```

As you can see, I am trying to retrieve a few column values, but java derby tool says:

> ERROR 42884: No authorized routine named 'LIKE' of type 'FUNCTION' having compatible arguments was found.

How can I got about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), I think. I'm not sure I understand what result you're aiming for, but what you wrote there is like no SQL I've ever seen.

Comment: Hey, no need to apologize. We're all still learning, all our lives. Check out the link on the word JOIN and see what it's about.

Comment: I made the query into a scalar query but can you tell me if it's possible to use join in a scalar subquery?

Comment: http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/scalar_subqueries.html#scalar5 > At the end of this page is a solution for making sclar subqueries return multiple rows, is this oracle specific? can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

AS evilpenguin mentioned, you need to use a join

```
  select app.employees.id, app.employees.name, app.employees.current_bp, 
app.designation.designation from app.employees, app.designation where 
app.employees.id like 'khsn?' = app.designation.desig_id like 'khsn?';
```

could be (if I understand you correctly)

```
SELECT EMP.id, EMP.name, EMP.current_bp,
       DES.designation
FROM   app.employees AS EMP
INNER JOIN app.designation AS DES
       ON SUBSTR(EMP.id,0,4) = DES.desig_id
WHERE app.employees.id like 'khsn?'
```

Note, this is matching against the literal "khsn?" string.

If you want a wildcard, it should be 
    WHERE app.employees.id like 'khsn%'

which would match anything starting with "khsn"

**EDIT**

Added SUBSTR based on OP's comments

Comment: my employees table has ID column which holds 8 character IDs for example "khsnC001", "khsnA001" etc. now my designation table holds desig_id like "khsnC", "khsnB" etc. I want to retrieve all employees from employees table matching "khsn_" and all those designations matching "khsn_" too.

Comment: Ok i made some progreess here's how my query looks now

select * from app.employees where app.employees.id like 'khsn%' in (select app.designation.desig_id from app.designation);

but since scalar queries are only allowed to return one row, i can pull in desgination from designation table